# Power Supply Interview Questions

Tags: voltage, power, current, dc-dc-converter, buck

I recently attended a Electronics interview.

I was asked this question - What should I take care in a buck converter layout?

One of my response was like - To place all the associated capacitors, feedback resistors in the same layer.

His question - What if the inductor and the IC and the external switching MOSFET are in different layer.

I thought it might cause ringing and said the same.

His follow up question was - How would you identify ringing without probing or testing?

I said we might get some noise. Is it correct or any other answer for this?

Comment: I'm not sure the layer matters as much as having them all close to each other. Trying to pass large currents through vias isn't great, but you can do it if necessary (use lots of vias, not just one).

Comment: it might be correct, but you might get any number of other correct answers to the same question.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. So, the primary challenge if the components are in different layers, is pushing the output current through the vias?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, thank you. I just guess the answer. But still don't know on why we would get some noise if there is ringing. Would you help on this?

Comment: Well, that's a very different question than what you've stated in your question, so which question do you really want an answer to?

Comment: I understand. Ideally, would be happy to understand both. But would like to learn any one concept at a time.

Comment: i would have said 'I would seek to minimize the loop area of the high current high frequency traces'.   There are some great application notes from TI and others that will teach you alot more than you can get from a forum.

Comment: I'm just a spectator here, not a EE, but I've been on both sides of the interview process more than a few times, and I can tell you that the interviewer isn't trying to find out whether you know the "correct" answer. The interviewer is affording you an opportunity to talk about some subject—switching power supply design in this case. It's not merely for you to show off the depth of your knowledge, but also, to show off your ability to put that knowledge into words (and often, into whiteboard sketches). ...to show how you will communicate with and get along with your future team-mates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I said we might get some noise. Is it correct or any other answer for
> this?

I think I would have mentioned a little more about parasitics, I've noticed over the years that some people neglect them. Being able to calculate/model parasitics is essential to many types of electrical engineering but especially in SMPS/Power engineering.

Being able to calculate how much inductance/resistance a trace or wire contributes to a designs and accurately modeling that can make or break some SMPS designs. In the few SMPS designs I've done sometimes I'll use a tool like "saturn PCB design tool" to calculate trace and via inductance and then use that in the spice model.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, would noise be an answer?

Comment: Either that or do calculations, a good designer will know what the ringing will be and design around that, then measure the expected noise and they should be about the same.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to learn the concepts behind your interviewers questions, then start in the following learning order.

1. Learn how a buck converter circuit works in principle.
2. Learn to identify which parts of a buck converter circuit has high dV/dt or dI/dt values (superfast transients).
3. Learn how you can mitigate/reduce these transients.

With this background, you will be able to give like 10 answers to the interviewers one question.